# Data gridview values in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have data you can see in the picture.

I want to get data from row 1 and col 3 (VEd,y) in my example is value 13 and store this value in a variable. Can someone help ?

[image]

Comment: `dim cellValue = DataGridView1(2, 0).Value`. Indexing start from `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to access the contents of a DataGridView named dgv at known indices is:

```
Dim o as Object = dgv.Rows(1).Cells(3).Value
```

But what if the columns have their order changed later?  If you know the column names of your columns, you could get their index (DataGridViewColumns have an Index property).  This avoids bugs when rearranging columns in the future.  In that case, you can also be certain of the type of data inside that cell, so you can more safely cast your `Value` object to the right type:

```
Dim xMmIndex as Integer = xMmColumn.Index
Dim o as object = dgv.Rows(1).Cells(xMmIndex).Value
Dim xMm as Integer = Convert.ToInt32(o)
```

When the columns were created, they were given names and column types.  You can find or edit these via the WinForms GUI-based designer by clicking the little arrow at the upper right of the DataGridView, then Edit Columns:

[image]

If your columns were not named, they are probably defaulted to their type with a number after it, such as DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1 or NumericUpDownColumn2.

And I'd recommend not hard-coding the row to an index of 1 either; you might get the row from looping over the DataGridView's SelectedRows property, for example.